# Using cuda shared memory efficiently for storing characters

Tags: c, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

Let's say I have to process 8 bit image pixels. I want to allocate shared memory to store those pixel values, and use in my kernel.

Now the issue is memory in shared memory banks are allocated in 32 bit. A character (8 bit pixel value) will be stored padded by sequence of 24 zeroes. This will result in huge memory loss.

So what would be the best way to store pixel values in shared memory, avoiding wastage of memory ?

Comment: Store 4 pixels per bank block ?

Comment: @Michael can you give a sample code to demonstrate your idea? DO you think that this will NOT lead to Bank Conflict?

Comment: Yes that will lead to bank conflict except if you treat 4 pixels per thread.

Comment: @Michael So you mean I will use a structure with 4 pixel members ?  Can you give a line of code to demonstrate your idea and put this as an answer ?

Comment: "A character ... will be stored padded by a sequence of 24 zeroes" Not sure what you're getting at here.  This is not correct.  If you define `__shared__ char my_chars[32];` there will be a sequence of 32 chars occupying 8 contiguous 32-bit locations in shared memory with no padding.

Comment: @RobertCrovella If I am accessing one char per thread, my understanding was that each char would be allocated in a different bank. for example char1->bank 0, char2->bank 1 and so on. all these spaces are 32 bit wide, that means only 8 bits will be used , rest will be zero padded.

Comment: That's not correct. I repeat:  if you define `__shared__ char my_chars[32];` there will be a sequence of 32 chars occupying 8 contiguous 32-bit locations in shared memory with no padding.  The way that you access it per thread does not affect how it is stored/allocated.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for clarifying my doubt, I got your point. But still there will be bank conflict if access is one thread per char?  So Michael's idea will remove this bank conflict.  Am I right now?

Comment: No, Michael's idea will not necessarily prevent a bank conflict.  His code *as written* does not present bank conflicts, but that has nothing to do with the grouping of 4 chars into a single struct.  It has to do with the fact that the code accesses elements sequentially.  I can group 4 pixels into a struct just as his code shows, and depending on what I can do I can still have bank conflicts.  Furthermore, I can not make use of the 4 pixels in a struct idea, but avoid bank conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

Use a structure to store 4 pixels on a 32 bits block.
Treat an entire block per thread to avoid bank conflicts and non-coalescing accesses.

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned char pixels[4];
} FourPixels;

__global__ void myKernel(FourPixels* gpixels)
{
  extern __shared__ FourPixels spixels[];

  int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  //copy on shared memory
  spixels[id] = gpixels[id];

  //example : remove blue component
  spixels[id].pixels[0] &= 0xFC;
  spixels[id].pixels[1] &= 0xFC;
  spixels[id].pixels[2] &= 0xFC;
  spixels[id].pixels[3] &= 0xFC;

  //copy result on global memory
  gpixels[id] = spixels[id];
}

__host__ int main()
{
  FourPixels* mypixs;
  cudaMalloc(&mypixs, 4*sizeof(FourPixels));

  myKernel<<<1, 4, 4*sizeof(FourPixels)>>>(mypixs); // 16 pixels !
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  cudaFree(mypixs);
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Also, a `__device__` function can be called from the kernel to avoid having to duplicate up the code for each byte.

Comment: @RogerDahl Are you talking about " remove blue component" in the above code?

Comment: @gpuguy: Yes. A separate function might not make sense for something very simple like the specific example, but I would make a device function if the duplicated code was more than a line or two.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some misconceptions floating around, so I thought I would add an answer as well, instead of more comments.  As a preface, let me state that I don't intend to explain in detail how bank conflicts arise.  There are webinars you can take, and plenty of other questions on SO, if you want to understand that.

1. From the standpoint of storage space efficiency, there is no lack of efficiency in storing an array of `char` (or `unsigned char`, I will use `char` in this discussion but there is no difference between the two for this discussion) in shared memory:

   ```
   __shared__ char my_chars[4096];
   ```

   All of the bytes in the above declaration will be packed contiguously with no intervening padding.  This is true regardless of how we access such an array.
2. From the standpoint of memory bandwidth utilization efficiency, accessing 32 bits per thread or 64 bits per thread will always give maximum memory bandwidth utilization, and so the grouping of 4 pixels/bytes/chars per thread would help there.  Note that we don't really need a special `struct` to accomplish this, even with my `char` array definition, but certainly the 4 pixel struct definition suggested by Michael makes it obvious how to do this.   Note that in this reference I am not saying that *every* aspect of Michael's code leads to better performance. Obviously, when individual pixels are being accessed, then we are not talking about 32 bits vs. 8 bits, so my comments here don't apply to Michael's code.  But, for example, in Michael's code, there is this line which transfers data from global memory to shared memory:

   ```
   spixels[id] = gpixels[id];
   ```

   Assuming the compiler identifies the structure copy as a 4 byte transfer, this will have better memory bandwidth utilization, (both on the global side and on the shared side).
3. From the standpoint of bank conflicts, bank conflicts arise out of *access patterns*, not principally out of how the data is stored in memory.  On cc 2.0 and newer devices, the previous definitions of storage and access pattern:

   ```
   __shared__ char my_chars[4096];
   int idx=threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
   char my_pixel = my_chars[idx];
   ```

   do *not* give rise to bank conflicts. A bank conflict could arise based on access pattern, for example:

   ```
   char my_pixel = my_chars[128*idx];
   ```

   would lead to the pathological case of 32-way bank conflicts.  But a similar pathological access pattern can be constructed if we are accessing 32 bits per thread; the "4 pixel struct" method does not prevent such bad access patterns.

Comment: @ Robert Regarding your point no. 2, you talked about cacheline. Is there any cache between register and the shared memory? I doubt if there is any concern of coalesced and non-coalesced  access in shared memory context.

Comment: You are correct.  I have removed references to the cache.  However, the concept of coalescing for global memory accesses is related to the concept of bank conflicts with shared memory.  Access patterns that lead to coalescing in global memory also tend to avoid bank conflicts in shared memory.  However the concepts also differ as well.

Comment: Regarding 2 above (updated) wrt Michaels'code I understand that at any point of time thread 0 and thread 1 (consider two threaded application only) will NOT access consecutive memory locations, because the first member of each structure will not be adjacent Then what is the reason for having better bandwidth utilization wrt Michael's code (also note that each thread is accessing 4 values but serially)? Appreciate if you can give an explanation in the answer for sake of everyone's eyes

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.  I didn't say that every aspect of Michael's code was better, even for this consideration.  Only where we are talking about 32bit vs. 8bit accesses.

Comment: Can the compiler combine 4 consecutive 8-bit shared memory accesses to one 32-bit access? That would seem to mean that the compiler must be sure that the byte pointer being passed in is 32-bit aligned, and can it know that?

Comment: I'm not sure I can adequately address this in comments.  The structure pointers I reference in my answer e.g. `spixels[]` are not byte pointers.  The structure pointers must be naturally aligned.  I don't know if you're referring to the structure copies or the individual accesses to the pixels.  The individual accesses to the pixels cannot be combined by the compiler.

Comment: What prompted the question was this section in (2), "Note that we don't really need a special struct to accomplish this, even with my char array definition, but certainly the 4 pixel struct definition suggested by Michael makes it obvious how to do this." I was thinking that the alternative to using a struct is to use 4 8-bit shared memory accesses. But maybe you were thinking more in terms of casting and then extracting each byte from the word?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of casting a (properly aligned) `char` pointer to a 32 bit type (e.g. `unsigned int`) pointer.